How to combine polygons using a same ID in the current layer without creating a new layer using python?
I have many polygons that need to be combined bu attributes. The problem is that the result of the merge must be saved in the original layer without creating a new one.
I used this function but it creates a temporary layer
processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':'D:\\shp.shp','FIELD':[],'SEPARATE_DISJOINT':False,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})


The text TEMPORARY_OUTPUT suggests it is doing exactly what you asked it to do. Saving back over the input file would be a very bad idea (trust me) as you can find a problem but are unable to fix it as the input data has gone.
Much better to save it as a new file and then once you are happy with it copy or move it over the input file (though I still advice against doing that).
